# Swift SpriteKit async/await bug: Memory bug with Swifts new Concurrency and SpriteKit

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

We noticed when using async await with SpriteKit run function.

Self is retained until run action is completed which can cause memory leak.

```
 Task {
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
            await controller.startIntro()
            print("intro done")
        }
```

If you deallocate controller, memory won't be released until await is not completed.

calling: 
`scene.removeAllActions()`

cause memory leak.

Here is project reproducing steps with possible workarounds:

https://github.com/maradic/SpriteKitConcurrencyBug

Is this SpriteKit bug or am I doing something wrong?

Original apple forum post:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/701295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess everything here works normally. That is how `await` works. It waits for its `async` friend to finish. You have this:

```
Task {
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
        await controller.startIntro()
        print("intro done")
    }
```

This can make potentially a strong cycle cause all variables are implicitly retained inside that block. Only when Task is completed, variables will be released. If You observe better Your `secondWorkAround()` method, You will see that by going back in first two seconds, a retain cycle will still occur (well, view controller will be alive until `SKAction` doesn't end). Cause Your action is finite, thats not a biggie. But imagine if You had some sequence that runs forever.

That should be solved with `[weak controller] in` and after You implement that (plus remove the specific action), You will see that controller deallocates immediately after `sleep` is finished (after 2 seconds).

Also, doing something like `scene.removeAllActions()`, won't work. Cause You are removing actions that are running on scene, not on its nodes. Thus, task doesn't end when You get back to previous screen.

Now Your `firstWorkAround()`, well its quite hackish :) I wouldn't do that. It speeds up a scene, thus action that is run in async way from Your `startIntro()` method gets ended, and task is finished.

But I wouldn't go that way, it's not how is meant to work. Point is that You await the action from `startIntro()` to finish. That will happen if it finishes "naturally", or if You stop it. And legit way would be to find [action by key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483138-action) and to stop it.

Note that You have something like this too:

```
 scene.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*") { (node, _) in
            node.removeAllActions()
 }
```

This will go recursively trough every node and remove actions for it. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/searching_the_node_tree). Hope this makes sense a bit, and it helps.